# How can a person promise to be מליץ יושר for a person after their death?

Tags: jewish-books, death, tzaddikim, zechut-merit

I have seen several references where certain gedolei yisroel of yesteryear, promise that if a person learns their works, these Rabbonim will be מליץ יושר (advocate) for them in the olam haemes.

Examples include the following:

[Rav Yechezkel Abramsky zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehezkel_Abramsky) about whom it is related:

> שנפטר בכ"ד אלול תשל"ו...וציוה שמי שילמוד בספריו יהיה מליץ יושר עליו בעוה"ב
>
> Who died on the 24th Elul 5736 (1976)...and commanded that whoever would study in his books, he would be an advocate for them in the Next World.

[As related in [Rivevos Ephraim, Orach Chaim, cheilek beis, p. 248](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1534&st=&pgnum=248&hilite=)]

In the [hakdomo](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41755&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=) (fifth perek - letter beis) to the sefer מלא העומר, by the Plotzker Gaon, [Rav Aryeh Leib Zuenz zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Leib_ben_Moses_Zuenz) it writes the following:

> "והנה כבר נודע לנשגב את אשר הגיד הגאון לפני פטירתו "שמי שישתדל בהדפסת ספריו יהיה לו למליץ
>
> And behold it is already known what the gaon said before his death - "that one who expends efforts to print his books, he will be to him as an advocate.

Similarly, it is written about the [Avnei Nezer zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Bornsztain) as referenced by [Rav Aryeh Tzvi Frumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Tzvi_Frumer), the Kozhiglover Rav, in his sefer [Eretz Tzvi p.242](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21030&st=&pgnum=259&hilite=):

> ובזה מובן מה שהגיד אדמו"ר זצוקללה"ה קודם פטירתו, שאם ילמדו בספרים שלו יהיה למגן ולעזר גם אחר פטירתו ממש כמו בחיים
>
> And this is understood what the Admor of blessed and holy memory related before his death, that if they learn his seforim he will protect and help even after his death just like in life.

And indeed this is something that the Avnei Nezer reiterated in his own writings - [Avnei Nezer, cheilek 5, siman 122](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1346&st=&pgnum=205&hilite=), by stating:

> ואם היה מעיין בדבריי מעט עיון היה מרויח לו טובה הרבה
>
> And if he studies deeply my words a little, it would benefit him a great deal.

So on to the question....

How can anyone make the claim that they will advocate for a person after they die. Do we have the ability to intercede in the heavenly realms? I appreciate these are great tzaddikim, and perhaps their desire that people learn their seforim is so that they can continue to accrue more zechuyos (merits) in the next world. But is it possible to promise such a thing?

Comment: You think that's weird, check out YD 179:14

Comment: Interesting interpretation of Avnei Nezer 5:122. I wouldn't have understood it like that.

Comment: How would you have learnt it?

Comment: Yeah, like chortkov2 said: The Avner Neizer doesn't seem to be saying that at all.

Comment: @MichoelR - how would you read it?

Comment: Why isn't there a benefit any time someone studies Torah deeply? I can't tell precisely what he means.

Comment: @MichoelR - he is talking specifically about his own Torah - 'anyone who learns from my words'

Comment: Still may not mean, Because of my influence in the next world. It may be he thinks his Torah will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of Tzadikim interceding on behalf of others in heaven predates Mattan Torah. Yaakov buried Rachel in Kever Rochel in order that she should daven for those being led into Golus when the Beis Hemikdush was destroyed. Being a meilitz yoser however is no guarantee of results. In fact the Medrash relates how ALL the Avos and Imohos and Moshe Rabbeinu davened when the Beis Hemikdush was destroyed  but Hashem ONLY  answered RocheL with  מִנְעִי קוֹלֵךְ מִבֶּכִי וְעֵינַיִךְ מִדִּמְעָה כִּי יֵשׁ שָׂכָר לִפְעֻלָּתֵךְ נְאֻם ה וְשָׁבוּ מֵאֶרֶץ אוֹיֵב

None of the seforim quoted here promise results. They only promise effort on behalf of those who learn them. The Gemora (Chullin 7B) says that Tzadikim are even bigger in their death than during their lifetimes so if they can daven and be melamed zchus on people in this world they certainly can do it in the next to an even greater degree